# console.error causing service worker to fail to initialize

Tags: service-worker

I tried to research about this in several places (even ChatGPT), and I didn't receive any real answer, so I have to ask here (though I hope this question is not rejected).

I am creating a Chrome extension with a service worker. If, at initialization time, the service worker writes a `console.error`, the service worker won't start.

I couldn't believe this when I saw it, but it is a consistent error. If I change to console.info or below, the error will not show up.

The question here would be where is this documented? And, does anyone else has seen this "issue"?

Thanks